# What is the solution for Conflict with dependency app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild

Tags: android, annotations

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'. > Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

For appcompat-v7:26.1.0. the test should be test:runner:1.0.1 & espresso-core:3.0.1'

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    }
```